# how to change ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone's TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activeadmin

While using ActiveAdmin, I want to display time in specific timezone. 
The type of variable is ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

I google it but all the answers were to set default timezone for ActiveAdmin. How can I display time with specific timezone without doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than patching ActiveSupport::TimeWithZones to modify how it delivers timezones, I'd recommend using BaseCamp's [local_time gem](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time) for displaying local time client-side.